# Errors when trying to upgrade Linux kernel

Tags: kernel, apt, upgrade, dpkg, error-handling

I've gone to upgrade my machine as I do every day and I've received the following errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Hit:1 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                              
Hit:3 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                                                         
Hit:4 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                          
Hit:5 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64 (4.19.98-1+deb10u1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-8-amd64
pigz: abort: write error on <stdout> (No space left on device)
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 pigz 28
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-8-amd64 with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I believe the following line might be the cause of the issue, but I'm unsure how to fix:

```
pigz: abort: write error on <stdout> (No space left on device)
```

## System info

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ls -la /boot/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Apr 29 08:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root     4096 Feb 11 05:39 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   206361 Nov 11 00:30 config-4.19.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   206194 Apr 27 06:05 config-4.19.0-8-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   186598 Sep 20  2019 config-4.9.0-11-amd64
drwx------  3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Feb 11 05:39 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 62662464 Feb  9 19:01 initrd.img-4.19.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 62708576 Feb 11 05:39 initrd.img-4.19.0-8-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 47360778 Oct 25  2019 initrd.img-4.9.0-11-amd64
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Jan 27  2019 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3410671 Nov 11 00:30 System.map-4.19.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3408461 Apr 27 06:05 System.map-4.19.0-8-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3203475 Sep 20  2019 System.map-4.9.0-11-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5270768 Nov 11 00:30 vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5274864 Apr 27 06:05 vmlinuz-4.19.0-8-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4249376 Sep 20  2019 vmlinuz-4.9.0-11-amd64

$ sudo dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.19.0-6-amd64             4.19.67-2+deb10u2                    amd64        Linux 4.19 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
iF  linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64             4.19.98-1+deb10u1                    amd64        Linux 4.19 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ii  linux-image-4.9.0-11-amd64             4.9.189-3+deb9u1                     amd64        Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64                      4.19+105+deb10u3                     amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)

$ sudo cat /var/log/dpkg.log
2020-04-29 08:54:32 startup packages configure
2020-04-29 08:54:32 configure linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64:amd64 4.19.98-1+deb10u1 <none>
2020-04-29 08:54:32 status half-configured linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64:amd64 4.19.98-1+deb10u1

$ df
Filesystem                  1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          3987600         0   3987600   0% /dev
tmpfs                          804084      9672    794412   2% /run
/dev/mapper/debian--vg-root 220799920 117407476  92106736  57% /
tmpfs                         4020420    165216   3855204   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         4020420         0   4020420   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1                   114854440  84891720  24085372  78% /mnt/Extended
/dev/sda2                      241965    208213     21260  91% /boot
/dev/sda1                      523248      5220    518028   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                          804084        20    804064   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdd2                    15006688     41004  14183656   1% /media/squire/GENERAL
```

Comment: You answered your own question, you're out of space to store the new kernel. Look for older kernels to delete (not the one you're currently running of course, and also maybe leave one or two in `/boot/`) and then retry the upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can free up some space by deleting the 4.9 kernel:

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-4.9.0-11-amd64
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `/boot` partition is close to full. You can possibly free space by [removing old kernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels) before installing the update. If they were automatically installed, you can simply run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` as explained in the link.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the Debian 10 upgrade that caused the same issue on one of my servers, with the initrd.img-4.19.0-9-amd64 that was generated being 128MB when all the previous ones had been about 30MB!

I just ended up resolving this when the latest apt-get update showed there was a new image available and so I replaced the huge version with a copy from another server (just in case there was an issue with the upgrade) and installed the upgrade. After the upgrade built a new initrd.img-4.19.0-9-amd64, it was 29MB much like the version on my other servers.